# Storing Items in Table View in An Array

Tags: iphone

I currently have an iPhone app set up with a table view full of exercises. What I want to be able to do is store these exercises in an array (or something similar) once they are clicked on so that they can be used to form a workout, which could be saved and accessed at a later time?

I do want to have this information persistently stored, so should I be using a database? If someone could point me in the right direction, I would be very much appreciative.

Answer (score 1):

Add a mutable array property, add instances of nsindexpath to it / remove them from it in tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:, serialize the array into NSUserDefaults.

Comment: How would you go about adding the instance path to the array?

Comment: [<nsmutable array instance> addObject:<nsindexpath instance>]

Answer (score 0):

@TopChef

Yes surely you can use sqlite database. 
Download the mozilla firefox and download the add ons of mozilla and after that you can create the database for your app. Now a days mostly developers are using database for such type of requirement. Even i also have the same requirement and using this technique. :-) So be happy ..